# How do I change a letter from lowercase to uppercase without using toUppercase?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know how this without using a function. I've tried using `String.fromCharCode` but I guess I didn't do it right. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post what you tried.

Comment: What's the point of avoiding `toUpperCase`? You've said you want to do it "...without using a function..." and then promptly talked about a **function** (`fromCharCode`).

Comment: Look at an ASCII chart http://www.asciitable.com/ and it's easy to see that you can convert from upper/lower just by adding or subtracting 32 from the decimal value of the char.

Comment: @asawyer: Sure.... Cause all the world only uses ASCII.  :)

Comment: @cHao Meh, if you don't put effort into the question don't expect effort from the answers. Low Ascii math covers mostly everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting characters from lower case to upper case is non-trivial if you want to support anything other than the English letters `a` through `z`. There are mappings involved in the Unicode database.

So `toUpperCase` is the right tool for this job. According to [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.16), it uses the Unicode database to select the appropriate upper case character. (That link is to `toLowerCase` because `toUpperCase` just says it does the same thing as `toLowerCase`, but for upper case.)

But if you only supported the English letters `a` through `z`, those are represented by character codes 97 through 122, inclusive. `A` through `Z` are represented by character codes 65 through 90, inclusive. So:

```
var upperChar = String.fromCharCode(lowerChar.charCodeAt(0) - 32);
```

would do it. But I strongly recommend *not* doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into ascii table [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif).
A = 65
...
a = 97

And do not forget that is not the right way to do it, but if you need to go to this level of programing this is the way. This will work for ascii (English letters) only.

There will be a lot of minuses but this is the answer on your question :).

Answer (score 1):

ASCII value of 'A' is 65 while 'a' is 97. Difference between them is 97 – 65 = 32
So if we will add 32 in the ASCII value of 'A' then it will be 'a' and if will we subtract 32 in ASCII value of 'a' it will be 'A'. It is true for all alphabets.
In general rule:

Upper case character = Lower case character – 32

Lower case character = Upper case character + 32