# How i can Capitalize without using toUpperCase

Tags: javascript, capitalize

How I can capitalize a word without using .toUpperCase() ... string.prototype.capitalize or Regex maybe ?

Only the first letter of the word.

I have this, and works perfectly:

```js
text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1);
```

But i don't want use .toUpperCase().

PD: only use JS, not CSS.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the need ?

Comment: can use text-transform:capitalize via in css

Comment: @PranavCBalan just learning

Comment: counter question: Why would you want to write your own, probably resource wasting function for that instead of using an internal function that already exists?

Comment: This has been answered many times. the psuedo code is, `sentence.split(' ').map(w => w[0].toUpperCase() + w.substr(1)).join(' ');`

Comment: @AlvaroGlez :  why not `toUpperCase()` ??

Comment: @VinodLouis hey, that's clever! :D But not a js solution! ;)

Comment: @VinodLouis only JS, just edit the post. Thanks!

Comment: @CallumLinington errm, but your code DOES make use of toUpperCase ;-)

Comment: @Connum how do you make a char go to upper case without using the function designed to do that. use a char table.... I'm guessing he doesn't want to upper case the entire word, hence why he says not using that on the word, however, each letter at the beginning of the word needs upper case. You need to use upper case and be pragmatic, otherwise this is a fruitless exercise

Comment: Since his update, I revise my comment to just - don't do this, if you want to achieve it rewrite the language....

Comment: Without toUpperCase : String.fromCharCode(word.charCodeAt(0)-32)+word.substring(1); ;) (ascii only)

Comment: Your answer is here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272516/how-do-i-change-a-letter-from-lowercase-to-uppercase-without-using-touppercase?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: All the answers given so far work for letters within the ASCII range, but fail e.g. for `"überlegung"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) and [charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) to switch between lower and upper letter:

```js
function capitalize(word) {
    var firstChar = word.charCodeAt(0);
    if (firstChar >= 97 && firstChar <= 122) {
        return String.fromCharCode(firstChar - 32) + word.substr(1);
    }
    return word;
}

alert(
    capitalize("abcd") + "\n" +
    capitalize("ABCD") + "\n" +
    capitalize("1bcd") + "\n" +
    capitalize("?bcd")
);
```

Comment: Damn, beat me to it. Yours is more elegant anyway

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir It will output `Hello i was born in the 90s!!!` as you probably already know.

Comment: Yeah sorry on the edit I was ust testing and pressed the button by mistake. Your code will fail if the string start with numbers though! Capitalize this: `90s kids!`!

Comment: It will also fail if the string starts with anything else that is not a letter...

Comment: @Connum Agree!! I just give him an example!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Correct, i've updated my answer to manage those cases.

Comment: Except, this only works with English language or languages fitting the ASCII table + UTF8 extension. Will not work for languages with codes in the UTF16 range > UTF8 (nordic languages, spanish, ++) .

Comment: Hello, Can  you please explain why did you  32 with char to minus the chars. I did not understand that part. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @GurkiranSingh ASCII characters are defined as follow : 65 to 90 are uppercased letters; 97 to 122 are lowercase letters; 91 to 96 are some symbols. the -32 move from lowercase to uppercase letters (-26) and we need to skip thoses chars from 91 to 96 (-6). The -32 is -26 + -6

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [asii case conversion trick](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/ascii-case-conversion-trick)

Check the below implementation with bit wise operators

## Code:

```
function toUpperCase(str) {
    var asciiCode = str.charCodeAt(0);
    if (asciiCode > 96 && asciiCode < 123) {
        // & ~(1 << 5) set the 6th bit to 1
        return String.fromCharCode(asciiCode & ~(1 << 5)) + str.slice(1);
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}
```

## Explanation

> To convert the lowercase alphabet to uppercase, we can xor the 6th bit

If you look at characters a..z, you'll see that all of them have the 6th bit set to 1.

```
a = 01100001    A = 01000001 
b = 01100010    B = 01000010 
c = 01100011    C = 01000011 
d = 01100100    D = 01000100 
e = 01100101    E = 01000101 
f = 01100110    F = 01000110 
g = 01100111    G = 01000111 
h = 01101000    H = 01001000 
i = 01101001    I = 01001001 
j = 01101010    J = 01001010 
k = 01101011    K = 01001011 
l = 01101100    L = 01001100 
m = 01101101    M = 01001101 
n = 01101110    N = 01001110 
o = 01101111    O = 01001111 
p = 01110000    P = 01010000 
q = 01110001    Q = 01010001 
r = 01110010    R = 01010010 
s = 01110011    S = 01010011 
t = 01110100    T = 01010100 
u = 01110101    U = 01010101 
v = 01110110    V = 01010110 
w = 01110111    W = 01010111 
x = 01111000    X = 01011000 
y = 01111001    Y = 01011001 
z = 01111010    Z = 01011010
```

Comment: What about `Hello, world!`!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Updated the answer with bit wise operator

Answer (score 0):

```
function capitalise(word){
    let asciiRef = word.charCodeAt(0);
    let newAsciiRef = asciiRef - 32;
    let newChar = String.fromCharCode(newAsciiRef);
    return newChar + word.substr(1);
}
```

Comment: You should explain how your code works, how it would answer the question, and which shortcomings it may have e.g. not properly capitalising valid non-ASCII letter characters and generally having undefined behaviour for anything other than lowercase ASCII characters.